# node.js odata-server mongodb unable to post related entity

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, odata, entity-relationship

I have been working on a node.js odata server based on this example: [How to set up a nodejs OData endpoint with odata-server](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-set-up-a-nodejs-odata-endpoint-with-odata-server)

I have everything working... I can read, update, insert, delete. But I am trying to associate a Journal with a Tasks and I am having problems.

I have tried several different ways outlined here: [Operations (OData Version 2.0)](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/operations/)

Here is my code:

```
/* global $data */
require('odata-server');

$data.Class.define("Task", $data.Entity, null, {
    Id: { type: "id", key: true, computed: true, nullable: false },
    Title: { type: "string", required: true, maxLength: 200 },
    Journals: { type: "array", elementType: "Journal"
        , inverseProperty: "Task" }
});

$data.Class.define("Journal", $data.Entity, null, {
    Id: { type: "id", key: true, computed: true, nullable: false },
    Entry: { type: "string" },
    DateInserted: { type: "string" },
    Task: { type: "object", elementType: "Task" , inverseProperty: "Journals" }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("obb", {
    Tasks: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Task },
    Journals: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Journal }   
});

$data.createODataServer(obb, '/api-v0.1', 2046, 'localhost');
```

**Question:**

Is this feature even available from [odata-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-server) what would the post look like to link a Journal to a Task?

I am using fiddler2 and composing a POST I have tried these urls:

```
//localhost:2046/api-v0.1/Tasks('the-id-of-a-task')/Journals
//localhost:2046/api-v0.1/Tasks('the-id-of-a-task')/Journals/$link
```

post body's I have tried:

```
{"Entry":"This is a test"}
{"url":"http://localhost:2046/api-v0.1/Journals('id-of-a-journal-in-the-db')"}
```

I have even tried to build out and post a Task with journals together and that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.